# Branch.io - setting up custom root domain

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate, branch.io, nameservers

I'm trying to setup a **custom root domain** in **branch.io**

I've set custom nameservers as requested, however after almost 2 days I still have the following issues:

1. the branch.io dashboard still shows a warning

> Domain is incorrectly set up; please use the nameservers below as your NS record.

2. I've created some quick links, however when I visit any of them on the browser, I get an SSL error (invalid certificate, certificate issued for a different domain) and an error page saying

> That link could not be found!

I've already contacted the official support but I didn't get a reply.

Thanks

Comment: Adding more details to the question would help. Details like - host, or branch settings screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

After contacting the official support, it turns out it is a known bug and engineers are currently working on a fix. It'll be fixed soon.